# How to Save pdf in shared folder using TCPDF

Tags: php, pdf, tcpdf

I m trying to save PDF in shared folder. But its giving me error. I manually checked that path is right or not. but its right. But still I m not able to generate PDF.

Here is my code

```
<?php
$file = "//ADMIN/testsor/SORPDF.csv"; 
$handle = fopen($file,"r"); 
$data= fgetcsv($handle); 
//print_r($data);exit; 
$filename="Test.pdf";
$filepath="\\\\ADMIN\\testsor\\pdf"; 
require_once('tcpdf_include.php');

// create new PDF document
$pdf = new TCPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);
$pdf->SetCreator(PDF_CREATOR);
$pdf->setFooterData(array(0,64,0), array(0,64,128));

if (@file_exists(dirname(__FILE__).'/lang/eng.php')) {
require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/lang/eng.php');
$pdf->setLanguageArray($l);
}
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetFont('times', '',11);
$pdf->setPage(1, true);
$txt = '
<table cellpadding="1" border="1" cellspacing="0" width="100%" class="main">
<tr><td class="cen">&nbsp;</td><td style="padding-right:7px" align="right"><strong>Signature</strong> </td><td colspan="3" align="center"  height="50px"><img src="'.$data[0].'" height="20px" width="100px" >
</td></tr>
<tr><td class="cen">&nbsp;</td><td style="padding-right:7px" align="right"><strong>Fitter`s Signature</strong> </td><td colspan="3" align="center" height="50px"><img src="'.$data[1].'" height="20px" width="100px" >
</td></tr>
</table>
 ';

$pdf->writeHTML($txt,1,null,null,null,null);
$fileNL = $filepath."\\".$filename;
$pdf->Output($fileNL,'F');

?>
```

Error

```
TCPDF ERROR: Unable to create output file: \\ADMIN\testsor\pdf\test.pdf
```

Answer (score 1):

make sure that file **\ADMIN\testsor\pdf\test.pdf** is not open anywhere when you run script. if it's open somewhere else then TCPDF can't open it.

Answer (score 0):

do you have the necessary permissions to write to ?
you can change it like this
chmod -R 0777 /pdf

Comment: How can I use it here ?

Comment: Could you please write full path

Comment: you dont use it here, basically you need to go to that folder and change the permission to write to. the error says it is like read-only, so easiest was possible is connect with ftp to your server and right click, you normalyy see something says in the menu "chmod" .

Comment: This one is shared folder's path.So I did not find the word like 'chmod'in share folder option

Comment: ok, lets to a different approac, can you create a basic file in that folder, if you can create a file with php in that folder it means you have the permissions, so it is tcpdf related, if you can not even create a basic file in shared folder than it is something to do permissions.

Answer (score 0):

if this is shared folder, contact the admin/owner of computer/server where the folder belong to, to give you access to read and write on the shared folder

Answer (score 0):

I Solved this issue. May be its also helps to other.
Here problem was its not saving the pdf in shared folder. 
I shared this folder for all users and also give full access.But still its not worked.
So I realized its something related to security I checked In folder->RightClick->Property->Advance share folder->Security.I found that here 'everyone' option(i.e added in share->group/username ) is not added. So I added and then its working.

Answer (score 0):

You have give permission in your server.

**ADMIN/testsor( Folder ) -> Right click -> Properties -> Security -> Edit -> {Select User} -> Allow Full Control Check-> OK**

and try again